# Jquery ajax response seems to ignore classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

When the page is first opened all of the formatting and functions that depend on `CSS` classes work exactly as they do, as soon as I call the `ajax` response it seems as if the classes are being ignored.

The `html`

```
<div id="selected_standards" class="touchcarousel black-and-white">     
    <ul id="standards_list" class="touchcarousel-container standards_display">
    <?php 
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM standards
                LEFT JOIN image
                ON image.imageID = standards.imageID_standard
                WHERE auditID_standard = '$audit_id'";
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){?>                    
       <li class="touchcarousel-item"><img src="<? echo $row['imageLocation']; ?>" width="200" ></li><? 
        }?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The php used for the ajax response

```
$output .='<ul id="standards_list" class="touchcarousel-container standards_display">';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){          
   $output .='<li class="touchcarousel-item" style="list-style:none; display:inline">';
   $output .='<img src="'.$row['imageLocation'].'" width="200" >';
   $output .='<p>'.$row['imageID'].'</p>';
   $output .='</li>';               
}
$output .='</ul>';
echo $output;
```

The ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/create_audit_standard_carosel.php',
    type:'POST',
    data: 'audit_id='+audit_id,
    success: function(response){
        $('#selected_standards').html(response);
        var myStylesLocation = "touchcarousel/touchcarousel.css";
        $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'+myStylesLocation+'" >').appendTo("head");
    }, // End of success function of ajax form
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});
```

I have tried using `json`, or using `.append` to add it to a list rather than replacing it, reloading the css, inline styling, everything, but as as the ajax call replaces the contents of the `div` the li and ul elements lose all of their classes despite the fact that the console html output shows the classes in place.

Just to add if I add a page reload to the ajax the formatting is back, but that kind of defeats the object of ajax

Comment: Your AJAX success function is adding a new stylesheet, maybe it's changing something relevant?

Comment: The style sheet added by the ajax is one of the style sheets loaded when the page first opens, I added it to the ajax to try and reload it after reading a similar question on stackoverfow

Comment: Try $("head").append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'+myStylesLocation+'" >');

Comment: @aerojun-thanks but didn't work

Comment: Have you used Developer Tools to see what styles are being applied to the elements?

Comment: I have managed to work out that the missing styles are actually in a js file.  Is there anyway of reloading it within the ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to achieve it, it's to change the style of your elements via the use of the class attributes.

For example :

CSS

```
.nonajaxed-display ul li {
    color: red;
    /* etc...*/
}

.ajaxed-display ul li {
    color: blue;
    /* etc... */
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="selected_standards" class="touchcarousel black-and-white nonajaxed-display">     
    <ul id="standards_list" class="touchcarousel-container standards_display">                
       <li class="touchcarousel-item">
           test
        </li>
        <li>
           // etc...
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/create_audit_standard_carosel.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'audit_id=' + audit_id,
    success: function (response) {
        $('#selected_standards').addClass('ajaxed-display');
        $('#selected_standards').removeClass('nonajaxed-display');
        $('#selected_standards').html(response);
    }, // End of success function of ajax form
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});
```

Sorry for my bad english.